# Not able to put text on image in table while creating PDF using XMLWorker

Tags: spring, css, itext

I am have html file and giving that to XMLWorkerHelper to parse it, so that it can generate PDF.

In Html. In table cell I can put text on image. but when I do

worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, isr);
it does not put text on image,

isr - it is ByteArrayInputStream of mockHttpServletResponse.

I have used all different kind of styling in html. but it is not working.

Please let me know how can I do this.