# iText's XmlWorker does not recognize border-bottom on table cell

Tags: itext, xmlworker, mvcrazortopdf

XmlWorker does not recognize border-bottom on table cell.

This is my code:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 20%; height: 40px; vertical-align: top; border-bottom: 1px solid gray">Your name</th>
            <td style="width: 80%; border-bottom: 1px solid gray"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="height: 40px; vertical-align: top; border-bottom: 1px solid gray">Your lastname</th>
            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm testing using this official tool:
http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/
(Click "html" button, under "font size", and paste code)

I'm also testing using iTextSharp + MvcRazorToPdf (two C# libraries).

Question:
**How can I get the border-bottom to work?**

Edit:
Acording to this compatibility summary: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm, the css property `border-bottom` should work fine with the html element `td` (`cell`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XMLWorker does not support for shorthand CSS properties in case side specific border styles. The global property "border" should be supported. It looks like a typo in the conformance list.
Please use the property full names instead:
`<td style="... border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: gray" ...>`

Comment: We will add support for this shorthands in the next iText release

Comment: its nice to see someone from iText answering. Thanks.

Comment: any idea about this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264170/not-able-to-put-text-on-image-in-table-while-creating-pdf-using-xmlworker